# jQuery window.bind('scroll') function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, scroll, window

Below code not work in firefox?
Can anyone tell what is wrong this code?

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () 
{
  var header = jQuery('.page-header');
  var main_container = jQuery('.parent-container-homepage .main-container');
      scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll > 351){
      header.addClass('fixed'); 
      main_container.addClass('fixed-active');
    }else{ 
      header.removeClass('fixed');  
      main_container.removeClass('fixed-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: above code is working on my firefox? What version you are using of firefox?

Comment: Firefox ver.64.0.2 .My Jquery Ver.jquery-2.1.1.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.min.js . What is your jquery version?

Comment: I just tried your code in stackoverflow site in inspect tool console. and It works here. Are you using two jquery together?

Comment: yes i have using two jquery

Comment: Remove one of jquery. Keep latest version